# How to optimize c# code requesting JSON using REST api

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, optimization

I have to make a c# application which uses REST api to fetch JIRA issues. After I run the tool I am getting the correct output but it is taking a lot of time to display the output. Below is the part of code which is taking the maximum time

```
var client =new WebClient();

foreach(dynamic i in jira_keys)
{
 issue_id=i.key;
 string rest_api_url="some valid url"+issue_id;
 var jira_response=client.DownloadString(rest_api_url);

 //rest of the processing
}
```

jira_keys is a JArray. After this there is processing part of the JSON in the for each loop. This is taking a lot of time as the number of jira_keys increase. I cannot apply multi-threading to this since there are shared variable issues. So please someone suggest some way to optimise this.

Comment: You could run the downloads concurrently. For every jira key, you could for example use [`DownloadStringAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202\(v=vs.110\).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can fetch the responses from JIRA asynchronously.

```
var taskList = new List<Task<string>>();
foreach (dynamic i in jira_keys)
{
    issue_id = i.key;
    string rest_api_url = "some valid url" + issue_id;
    var jiraDownloadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => client.DownloadString(rest_api_url));
    taskList.Add(jiraDownloadTask);
}
Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());

//access the results
foreach(var task in taskList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
}
```